# how to use a webview to show a webgl URL

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, webgl

i want to create a web application which goes directly to one of WEBGL  samples on the internet and shows it in the application.can anyone help me please?

Comment: more contenxt please...

Comment: im trying to make a simple app using a uiwebView .and that app view is supposed to show the content of a  url which is the address of a webgl sample.

Answer (score 0):

found it.

```
   #import "WGLAppDelegate.h"

@implementation WGLAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

//  Class ADWebView = NSClassFromString(@"ADWebView");
//  UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView *)[[[ADWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds] autorelease];
//  [webView setWebGLEnabled:YES];

 UIWebView* webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)] autorelease];

id webDocumentView = [webView performSelector:@selector(_browserView)];
id backingWebView = [webDocumentView   performSelector:@selector(webView)];
[backingWebView _setWebGLEnabled:YES];

NSString* htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alphatexture" ofType:@"html"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]];
[webView loadRequest:request];

UIViewController* viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
viewController.view = webView;

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

@end
```

you can find the sample app here :"https://github.com/atnan/UIWebViewWebGL"